# Chrome update 26.0.1410.43 m takes more than 20 sec to load after postback

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

Does anyone already found the solution for the problem that chrome has after the latest update. When you post something to the server it takes chrome more then 20 seconds to load.

We checked the same site in IE and FireFox everything loads pretty quick.

Its seems to be a bug in the new update.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Another thread describing a possible cause:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/google-chrome-26-performance-issue.aspx